# Is it possible for a Hopfield network to have a stable state where all nodes are "off"?

Tags: network-programming, artificial-intelligence, state

For example, given the Hopfield network pictured in the diagram attached...[image: network], where all nodes are originally at 0 (or "off"), is it possible for this network to relax to all 0s (that is, remain in this state)? All 0s are supposed to be a stable state for this diagram, but that doesn't make sense to me, because in this state, the input to each node would actually be dotProduct((0 0.. 0),(input1, input2 ... inputn)) = 0. But 0 >= 0, so that would make each node turn "on"/1, right? Perhaps I just don't understand how Hopfield networks relax to a stable state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else was interested, I found the answer...

Since a Hopfield network is a form of BAM network, it works in this way (rough pseudocode):

`if(input dotted with weights > 0) node = "on"
else if(input dotted with weights < 0) node = "off"
else node remains the same`

Thus, for this network, each node is receiving an input of 0, so each node will remain off (stay the same as its current state).